# convert jQuery .on() into .bind()

Tags: jquery

Due to a restriction of my used software-framework, I have to use jQuery 1.6.2 but a jQuery-plugin uses the following code:

```
$('body').on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) { }
```

.on() isn't available in jQuery 1.6.2... How can I write this with .bind() instead of .on()?

Comment: damn it - I want the opposite of this question :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use delegate instead of bind

```
$('body').delegate(
    '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]',
    'click.tab.data-api', 
    function (e) {
        ... 
    }
);
```